# Download all files with some strings in their names

Tags: wget

On http://www.inf.usi.ch/carzaniga/edu/algo08f/schedule.html, I would like to download all pdf files of the name `*-2up.pdf`, for example, 
http://www.inf.usi.ch/carzaniga/edu/algo08f/intro-2up.pdf

Can that be done using wget in bash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve files recursively but only retrieve those that end in `2up.pdf`, try:

```
wget -r -nd -A 2up.pdf 'http://www.inf.usi.ch/carzaniga/edu/algo08f/schedule.html'
```

Explanation:

- `-r` tells `wget` to get files recursively
- `-nd` tells `wget` to keep all downloaded files in the current directory.  Otherwise, it would try to recreate the directory structure at `www.inf.usi.ch`.
- `-A 2up.pdf` restricts downloads to filenames ending with `2up.pdf`.

#### Refinement

When told to be recursive, `wget` will search through all html links looking for links to file that can be accepted.  If we know that all the files that we want are linked directly in the source URL, then we don't want this behavior.  To restrict the depth to which `wget` will search, use the `--level` option:

```
wget -r -nd -A th-2up.pdf -A schedule.html --level=1 'http://www.inf.usi.ch/carzaniga/edu/algo08f/schedule.html'
```

The also demonstrates that multiple `-A` options can be used together.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What if I also would like to download the webpage itself besides those pdf files? (2) also it seems that `-A` will still download other files not ended in `2up.pdf` and then remove them, so it  seems to take very long to run to finish. Is it possible not to spend time on  files not needed?

Comment: @Tim It can be added it to the accept list: `wget -r -nd -A 2up.pdf -A schedule.html 'http://www.inf.usi.ch/carzaniga/edu/algo08f/schedule.html'`

Comment: Thanks. I see. But with `-A`, it will download everything, and remove those files not satisfy `-A`. That seems to take forever to finish running. Anyway not to spend time on files not needed?

Comment: @Tim It doesn't download "everything."  For example, it never downloads any of the non-2up PDFs.  But, it does download every html link in hopes of finding that it has a link to a 2up.pdf file.  If you know, however, that everything you want is in the `schedule.html` file, use `--level=1` as shown in the updated answer.